# error in module 'attr' when trying to run jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run jupyter notebook in windows 10 PC.
After installing miniconda and installed required library, I ran jupyter notebook and got following error.
I have been using jupyter notebook for few years and this is first time to see this error.
Does anyone came across this or know how to solve?

```
  File "C:\Users\katsuya.obara\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\py35\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\katsuya.obara\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "C:\Users\katsuya.obara\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\katsuya.obara\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\katsuya.obara\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\katsuya.obara\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\katsuya.obara\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\exceptions.py", line 141, in <module>
    @attr.s(hash=True)
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

Comment: Is it `attr`, or [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/)?

Comment: seems problem in module attr

Comment: It seems? Is it coming from your code, or another library that you’re using? It looks like the `jsonschema` module is at fault.

Comment: This error is not from my code. from library I am using. If it is error from jsonschema, how I can fix this?

Comment: It’s not super clear in your post, is this error occurring when you open the notebook, or when you actually run the code (or somewhere else)? Can you share the notebook?

Comment: It might also be useful to see the list of packages/libraries you have installed.

Comment: this *sounds* like you have a file named `attr.py` sitting in your working directory

Answer (score 8):

I believe the error will be solved if you install attrs which actually contains both the above mentioned packages.

```
$ pip uninstall attr
$ pip install attrs
```

But for that first you would need to uninstall your attr and then install attrs.
It should work as expected after the above changes.

Comment: What if one needs both at the same time?

Comment: Then skip step 1, do not uninstall!

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this link for detailed answer for the solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61074103/10362801

Just run below 2 commands in admin mode

`pip uninstall attr`

`conda install --force attrs`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and solved it by downgrading the attrs module to 19.2.0

Comment: this shouldn't matter, `jsonschema` is compatible with the latest `attrs` and `attr.s` has been present in every version that `jsonschema` can install against -- you might've change something else while upgrading / downgrading?

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 install --upgrade setuptools --user` solved the problem for me.

Hope this helps.