# Error while launching Jupyter Notebook - @attr.s(hash=True) AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, attributeerror, site-packages, python-attrs

I am not able to launch or open Jupyter Notebook. I have uninstalled and installed it multiple times, still get the same error which I have pasted below!

It's giving some 'Attribute Error'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ramya\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\Ramya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in 
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
File "C:\Users\Ramya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in 
from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
File "C:\Users\Ramya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in 
from .validator import validate, ValidationError
File "C:\Users\Ramya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in 
from jsonschema import ValidationError
File "C:\Users\Ramya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 11, in 
from jsonschema.exceptions import (
File "C:\Users\Ramya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\exceptions.py", line 152, in 
@attr.s(hash=True)
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

**Run Anaconda prompt as Admin**

`pip uninstall attr`

followed by

`conda install --force attrs`

**Now jupyter notebook should work.**

**Reason for the Issue :**

- attr pip package was installed into your user site-packages
  directory.
- That is loaded in preference to the site-packages
  directory maintained by conda.
- so every time you launch your Jupyter - attr package is been referred from your user site-packages instead of attrs from conda

Comment: This also applies if you didn't install attrs through your package manager (pacman in my case). The reason is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely created a module with the name `attr` that is shadowing the PyPI package required by `jsonschema`.

Comment: Not unless you installed https://pypi.org/project/attr/ by hand. Do you have a file named `attr.py` somewhere in your project?

Comment: Yes, attr.py is present inside, C:\Users\Ramya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages - I deleted that and reinstalled Anaconda. Now I'm able to launch Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search the file named 'attr.py' on your computer
2. Delete that file
3. Reopen Jupiter notebook or redownload it 
   This works on my computer, I have tried' pip uninstall attr' and it does not work, I guess we should do it by hand.